# How to delete Individual Pixels from Raster image in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, editing, pixel

I need to remove some pixels that are not in homogeneous land-covered areas.

How can I do that?

I was told to convert the raster into polygons, but that didn't work, as some pixels were merged together.

[image]

Comment: Check this page: [How To: Convert each pixel of a raster into a polygon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjnsfT9xvD9AhX5RfEDHaPhCOMQFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.esri.com%2Fen%2Ftechnical-article%2F000012696&usg=AOvVaw2Xl6VudpR2M16hrhUTKBpY)

Comment: I did, it was the first thing I tried to do, but I had no idea what to place in the X Y coordinates. The raster file I had had nothing on that information—just rows and columns values.

Comment: I recommend editing your question, to change it slightly so it asks how to remove specific pixels as converting to polygon is not the best way. Advise what extensions you have (e.g. the Pixel Editor is available with an Image Analyst license)